# Unable to Adjust TableView contentOffset after row insertion/deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have problem setting tableView contentOffset after inserting a row or deleting a row.

When i receive a new data, i update the datasource and insert row at top of tableView(tableView is inverted i.e. origin is at bottom). After inserting the row there is a case where i have to manually adjust its contentOffset but its not working the first time.

Note: The user does not scrolls the tableview when a new row is inserted

//insertion part

```
 self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)], with: .right)
```

//offset adjustment part

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 80)
```

The offset is not working properly. The tableview remains the same even after the offset is adjusted like above

Answer (score 1):

### Why are you setting the offset?

If you're setting the content offset to scroll to a specific cell then you should definitely be using

```swift
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
```

### Possible Fixes

if you're just trying to change the offset to something static, like 80 then its worth trying to use the set content offset method instead, like so:

```swift
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 80), animated: true)
```

Another possible way to fix this would be to try delaying the content offset change, I don't like this approach as its quite hacky but it's worth mentioning anyway, you could dispatchQueue the call like this:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 80)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ayrton , thank you for your response. Actually i can explain why i need to set the offset. As i mentioned it's an inverted tableview and hence the first row will be at the bottom. When user long taps the first row, i need to show an action sheet like custom view at the bottom of screen and this row must be moved above the action sheet like view. here i can't use tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true) as tableview won't scroll the first row to middle. Hence adding extra offset so that the row is shown at middle. I have tried your solution but that didn't help.